# Train multiple class in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

[i have data frame like this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgIlX.png)

i'm looking a way to train this data set so i tried it with sklearn with this code

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df[['city','text']], df[['1','2','3','4']], test_size = 0.40, random_state = 21)
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2,3), max_features=20000)
count_vect.fit(df['text'])

x_train =  count_vect.transform(train_x)
x_test =  count_vect.transform(test_x)
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(x_train, train_y)
```

but i got error like this

```
ValueError: Number of labels=2348 does not match number of samples=1
```

actually i don't know whether it's okay to train my data with its 4 labels directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the line:

```
x_train =  count_vect.transform(train_x)
```

You see, your `train_x` and `test_x` have two columns (from `df[['city','text']]`), but `CountVectorizer` only works with a single column. It just needs a single iterable of strings, not more. So you are right in doing:

```
count_vect.fit(df['text'])
```

since you are providing a single column only. But when you do supply `train_x` in `count_vect.transform(train_x)`, the `count_vect` ony take the column names and not the actual data.

Maybe you want:

```
x_train = count_vect.transform(train_x['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the shape of input `X` should be `[n_samples, n_features]`. If you check the shape of `X`, should be (2348, ).
The best way to transform `X` by

```
X = X[:, np.newaxis]
```